# MySQL Port is listening but unable to connect using Telnet

Tags: mysql, port

Checked my port is listening using netstat, Currports, and https://portchecker.co/, but whenever I use telnet on CMD it is unable to connect, how to fix this? thanks!

EDIT: MySQL config file

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: It is impossible to say from that info. Can you show us the output when you run netstat and also when you run telnet so we can get a bigger picture? If the port is listening on the correct port and ip you should be able to connect to it if you use the same ip+port. Firewall?

Comment: @MrApnea https://imgur.com/gallery/E32ZdKA , https://imgur.com/gallery/gpDEcsY, telnet says "Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed"

Comment: Hmmm to be honest I don't know what could be wrong. Are you trying netstat from the same computer where another tool works? portchecker is testing from the outside of your network, have you tried the same there? Could there be that it only works from remote computers? On netstat it says port 3306 4 times? Why are there 2 rows for TCP and 2 for UDP?

Comment: I have created another firewall rule for port 3306, maybe it would work but didn't, I deleted those 2 extra rules.

Here is my pastebin @MrApnea : https://pastebin.com/neBNADfh

Comment: Could you show the error when you try connecting with telnet?

Comment: @MrApnea Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

Comment: I should try to start from the same computer and work from there. Can you connect using telnet if you are on the same machine as the mysql-server. Then move to the next place and try there. Can you connect from the same network but not same computer? Maybe you could disconnect the network from the internet and turn off the firewall and see if its the firewall which is the problem? Unfortunatly I can't think of much more than to try one step at a time and see where the problem first start and then work from there.

Comment: From first to connecting to server from different computer but same network works for me, I also tried turning off the firewall but still doesn't work. I have tried port scanning online. I think the problem is on the ports, I have tried online scanning http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/# and 99% of them are closed, I saw one port "filtered". Can you check yours? So I can compare it to mine

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by 99% are closed? 3306 should be the only one open (if you don't have other services publicly available. It should say that the port is open (or responding as it says for me). Closed ports mean that there is no firewall but there is no program/service listening on that port. Filtered is that something is blocking your attempt to connect. That is most likely a firewall, either a local one or a router on the way.

Comment: Also, when you say that it works from another computer on the same network that tells me that your server is correctly setup. It is listening on port 3306 and are accepting connections from other computers. Most likely there is a router or firewall blocking port 3306 on the way. Normally this problems are on your gateway/router that is connected to the internet and are distributing it on to your network that blocks like this. Is this in your home or on a server at work?

Comment: 99% because I used netstat to see opened ports and a lot of ports are listening but when checked online they are nowhere to be found. This is in my home, I guess our ISP use some kind of firewall explains why I can't connect remotely, I asked our ISP they said they were not using any firewall, strange.

Comment: Ok. If you server is at home I would bet my money on your router. They normally have a firewall built into the router to protect customers. Even though your computer have an opening in the firewall you need to open it there as well, and also forward the port to your computer. When connections from the internet comes to your public ip the router will get the connection and if you fix the firewall it will let the connection pass but then it needs to know where to forward the connection. You need to tell it which local ip your server is located at.

Comment: If you haven't done any changes in your router you normally surf to http://192.168.1.1, if this don't work take your local ip and change the last part to a 1. If you need to enter any credentials they are normally found on the router or you can ask your ISP. The user/pass are sometimes standard values which can be found if you google the exact router name.

Comment: @MrApnea I have done port forwarding on my router, but if you say so I will try to use other router if I can and see if this is still a problem. My router is "Tenda" do you think that this have a firewall?

Comment: Almost all of these routers have a firewall of sorts. Your priority would be how to port forward the port (3306) to your local ip of the server where you have mysql running. There are multiple guides online, here are one: https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/8323/how-to-forward-or-open-a-port-on-a-tenda-router